# Separate list A/B -> B swi-prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I have a List [2/**4**,3/**6**,1/**2**,7/**5**] and I want to create a list consisting of only second numbers [**4**, **6** ,**2**, **5**].

I was thinking something like this:

```
newlist(L,L2):-
   newlist(L,A/B),
   newlist(A/B,B),
   newlist(B,L2).
```

That didn't work, any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have one list or two? What does `2/4` mean?

Comment: @Scott: You changed the meaning here. "only second numbers" is not "with the second numbers"

Comment: @false: I guess I don't understand.  The OP had `create a list only with the second numbers`.  I changed it to `create a list consisting of only second numbers`.  I'm not seeing the meaning change.  It's simply re-worded to read better.

Comment: @Scott: To my understanding you removed the context of second by removing the "the". Now it could equally mean "every other number". In any case such significant rephrasings do nobody a favor.

Answer (score 3):

Define a predicate for a single element:

```
pair_to_2nd(_/B, B).
```

Now apply this predicate to the list:

```
?- maplist(pair_to_2nd, [2/4, 3/6, 1/2, 7/5], L).
L = [4, 6, 2, 5].
```

Comment: Or just use the built-in predicate arg/3: maplist(arg(2), List0, List).

Answer (score 3):

```
listDenom([ ],[ ]).
listDenom([_/D|T],[D|V]) :- listDenom(T,V).
```

Answer (score -4):

Here is a solution using `string_to_list`.

```
splitList(A) :-  
    string_to_list(A, [_,_,_,A1,_,_,_,B1,_,_,_,C1,_,_,_,D1,_]),  
    string_to_list(A2, [A1]),  
    string_to_list(B2, [B1]),  
    string_to_list(C2, [C1]),  
    string_to_list(D2, [D1]),  
    write([A2,B2,C2,D2]).
```

**Example:**

```
?- splitList('[2/4,3/6,1/2,7/5]').
[4,6,2,5]
true.
```

Comment: -1. Sorry but there are many things wrong with the solution: the input should be a list (not an atom), it is not easily extendable to 5-element lists, A2 etc is not a number but a list, you shouldn't use write/1 to return results, ...

Comment: The `write` at the end was __not__ intended to substitute another returning function -- I merely added it for output purposes. I assume OP already has the required programming experience to modify it to accomplish the desired results. OP did also not specify how many elements of a list which was required for the function to split, so I decided to implement a simple, lucid function to solve OPs problem. This example which I provided is not intended to replace another, possibly more sophisticated, answer. As I mentioned, it's a mere example which will solve the problem.